# How to avoid the blink image when save the image after rotate animation?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am confusing the translate animation and rotate animation. In my game I use this two animations, after completing the animation I am save my image. In translate animation it is fine, but after completing rotate animation my image is blink once. See my code in bellow, please solve my problem……..

Why anyone not respond my question, it is not understand or I am asking any wrong question ? Please tell me reason.................

Thanks.

```
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.train); 
//1)
TranslateAnimation TAnimation=new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0,-100);//bottom to start
        TAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        TAnimation.setDuration(2000);
        TAnimation.setFillAfter(false);
        TAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
        //TAnimation.setFillBefore(true);
        Train.startAnimation(TAnimation);

TAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                RelativeLayout RL=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl);
                    param=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                param.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
                    Train.setLayoutParams(param);
                    Train.setImageBitmap(bmp);       
            }
        });
    //x and y values are exact position of compliting translateanimation position 
//2)
RotateAnimation RAnimation=new RotateAnimation(0,90,50,25);
        RAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        RAnimation.setDuration(2000);
        RAnimation.setFillAfter(false);
        TAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
        //RAnimation.setFillBefore(true);
        Train.startAnimation(RAnimation);
RAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                RelativeLayout RL=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl);
                    param=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                param.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);//x and y values are exact position of compliting translateanimation position 
                    Train.setLayoutParams(param);
                    Train.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

i had that problem but it's reaaaaally simple to fix. You don't need to implement the animation listener, simple don't do it (i had your problem because I use that way).

Do your animation and before call the animation method:
setFillAfter(true); //this save view at the end of the animation

Like so:

```
//my animation
final Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.rotate_up);
//hide login content
content.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//animContent = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.show_up);
rotation.setFillAfter(true);
//animate the arrow
arrow.startAnimation(rotation);
```

So, delete the listeners and change your setFillAfter(false) to TRUE. Will works ;)